# Prometheus - same metric with different labels is overridden before scraping

Tags: python, grafana, prometheus

I'm consuming various gauge metrics from Kafka to Prometheus using custom python app. The metrics needs to be consumed in more and less the same time (milliseconds). I'm able to successfully **scrape** only the last metric from below example as the first three are immediately overwritten.

```
my_metric{labelA = "aaa", labelB = "111"} 8
my_metric{labelA = "aaa", labelB = "222"} 12
my_metric{labelA = "bbb", labelB = "111"} 7
**my_metric{labelA = "bbb", labelB = "222"} 15**
```

I can get all four metrics getting **scraped** by setting them a unique metrics name e.g.:

```
my_metric_aaa_111{labelA = "aaa", labelB = "111"} 8
```

but this does not seem to be the best practice plus working with such metrics is very difficult in general later on in Grafana.

I can also push the metrics serially to be **scraped** and lower the interval of **scraping** in Prometheus config, but this is against the whole idea of the solution.

Apart from suggestions I'm completely unaware - is it possible to keep for Prometheus the same metric to be **scraped** where only label values differ? The only discussion I found on this is here with no answer: https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/issues/65.

If the above is not possible, can I somehow merge/join/combine metrics name later on in Prometheus/Grafana to be able to work with them based on their labels? Meaning remove the unnecessary ending `_aaa_111` in the example above to work back with everything as one metrics?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the first three are immediately overwritten` ? a metric is [uniquely identified by its name and the set of labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels). In your example, they are four different metrics and will be parsed as such.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for pointing me to the right direction. If for Prometheus all four metrics are considered to be unique I will need to look into the python producer app to find out what is wrong in there.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the Pushgateway job name, using a combination of the labels, or some unique value. So prometheus could scrape all your metrics, and they aren't overwriten by others.

In your case, if you export: `my_metric{labelA = "aaa", labelB = "111"} 8` to a job called, `some_job_aaa_111`.

You can test pushing some metrics manually: `echo "my_metric{labelA = \"aaa\", labelB = \"111\"} 8" | curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/some_job_aaa_111`

In Prometheus pushgateway you would see the next:

[image: Prometheus pushgateway jobs]

In Prometheus, the pushgateway job, becomes in a label that you can easily ignore, like the next output of Prometheus:

[image: Prometheus jobs]

Comment: Thanks Asier - this seems to work:) I was trying to workaround it  and have concatenated each metrics name from label values to e.g.  `my_metric_aaa_111{labelA = "aaa", labelB = "111"} 8` and then in Grafana use regex as `{__name__=~"my_metrics.+",labelA = "aaa"}`  which has been working as well but intuitively your solution is more efficient.  The main case is the python app that needs some redesign but this is a different topic.

Comment: HI @Asier Gomez --  So different "job" value is the only label that can make these metrics unique? I have a scenario that I have two tags/labels that are my "unique" strings, so I would like to use two labels to make a unique metric. Is that possible? Seems a little counterintuitive that labels don't make unique metrics.

Comment: @RinoBino You can play with "grouping key":  https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway

Answer (score 1):

You could also have different **grouping keys** when pushing to the push-gateway (and will look better than having the same prefix and different suffixes for job names)

Answer (score -1):

**Another Solution**: Make the scraping action be more frequently repetitive using `scrape_interval` attribute on `prometheus.yml` . If you based on minutes ,convert it to seconds or milliseconds to avoid race conditions.

```
- job_name: 'pushgateway'
  honor_labels: true
  scrape_interval: 50ms
  metrics_path: /metrics
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9091
```